# Does the Windows Store prevent app DLLs from changing maliciously?

Tags: windows, security, dll, uwp, windows-runtime

If I change any DLL of my UWP app that I purchased from the Windows Store, will the app crash if it runs?
If not, what can I do to prevent attacks on my application through DLL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application package which contains all of the dlls, exe, and resources is digitally signed, and that signature is checked at runtime so if you change any components of the package, the app will not run.